# Rails: Similar gems to FnordMetric?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Are there any other gems similar to [FnordMetric](https://github.com/paulasmuth/fnordmetric). The gem seems to do exactly what I want but I would like to evaluate some more options before I start using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [New Relic RPM](https://github.com/newrelic/rpm), [Engine Yard's Rails Metrics](https://github.com/engineyard/rails_metrics),  and [Visage](https://github.com/auxesis/visage)